# Unable to print the array which is passed to the constructor

Tags: java, arrays, class, oop, constructor

The problem is that I need to print objects' info including arrays which contain students' marks. But it throws rubbish instead. Also arrays must have 5 elements

```
public class Student {
    Student(String fullname, int group, int marks[]){
        this.fullname = fullname;
        this.group = group;
        this.marks = marks;
    }//constructor
    void display(){
        System.out.println("Named: " + fullname + " | Group: " + group + " | Marks: " + marks);//prints out the objects
    }
    int group;
    int marks[];
    String fullname;//class fields
    public static void main(String[] args){
        Student Matthew = new Student("Whatever 1",14, new int[]{9, 6, 8, 4, 5});
        Student John = new Student("Whatever 2",13, new int[]{4, 9, 5, 10, 7});
        Student Max = new Student("Whatever 3",14, new int[]{7, 10, 8, 9, 9});//objects
        Matthew.display();
        John.display();
        Max.display();
    }
}
```

Comment: Use Arrays::toString​. https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Arrays.html#toString(boolean%5B%5D)

Comment: `Arrays.toString(marks)`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What's the simplest way to print a Java array?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/409784/whats-the-simplest-way-to-print-a-java-array)

Comment: No, cos I was trying to print the array using constructor

Comment: Instead of telling us _"But it throws rubbish instead."_, show us what it actually prints...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use Arrays.toString(marks) to print the array values

```
public class Student {
    Student(String fullname, int group, int marks[]){
        this.fullname = fullname;
        this.group = group;
        this.marks = marks;
    }//constructor
    void display(){
        System.out.println("Named: " + fullname + " | Group: " + group + " | Marks: " + Arrays.toString(marks));
    }
    int group;
    int marks[];
    String fullname;//class fields
    public static void main(String[] args){
        Student Matthew = new Student("Whatever 1",14, new int[]{9, 6, 8, 4, 5});
        Student John = new Student("Whatever 2",13, new int[]{4, 9, 5, 10, 7});
        Student Max = new Student("Whatever 3",14, new int[]{7, 10, 8, 9, 9});//objects
        Matthew.display();
        John.display();
        Max.display();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If your'e not want to use the `Arrays.toString()` method (For aesthetic reasons) you can use that method:

```
public static String arrayToString(int[] array) {
        String arrayString = "";
        for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
            arrayString += array[i] + ", "; // Write here whatever you want to separate the array elements
        }
        return arrayString;
    }
```

Comment: At least you could've used StringBuilder. This will unnecessary create a lot of garbage.